# How can I configure the buttons on a Corsair gaming mouse?

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, mouse, input-devices, xinput

I bought a [Corsair M95 mouse](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-m95-performance-mmo-and-rts-laser-gaming-mouse-gunmetal-black) which I have used on my computer with Ubuntu Studio & Xubuntu 14.04, 15.04, and 15.10. It works out-of-the-box as a standard mouse, plus a button to slow down the cursor, but I haven't been able to fully utilize the *extra* buttons.

Firefox and some Thunar file manager recognize two of the buttons for forward/back. These seem to be the only programs I use that recognize anything.
The key-bindings settings in Team Fortress 2 recognizes the 3 *standard* mouse buttons as it should. But the rest of them are all recognized by the title "mouse4" as if they were all the same button (in Ubuntu 15.10, 2 of them are recognized as "mouse5").

If I use the Corsair program on Windows, then I can assign the mouse buttons to keys on my keyboard. It fortunately stores the profiles on the mouse; but I can't reconfigure them on Linux.  I would much prefer to have them recognized by my games (and even productive programs), so I can bind the mouse buttons in the settings for each game/program.

It appears that xinput recognizes it as 3 devices. Here is the output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ gspca_zc3xx                               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/934906/corsair-m95-gaming-mouse-too-sensitive-speed-too-fast-how-to-reduce-speed

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Corsair doesn't seem to want to support linux at all. However, there are a couple of work arounds. *Although it's important to note that I haven't tested these solutions myself. In addition, my M95 doesn't use the config that's on it when I'm on Linux, but it works on Windows.*

## 1: Windows VM

You could use VirtualBox and a Windows virtual machine to configure the mouse. Not ideal, but it works.

*Note: A second mouse is recommended.*

### Setup

1. [Download a Windows VirtualBox VM for IE and Edge development from Microsoft](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/linux/). These expire after 90 days, so remember to make a snapshot of the VM after you install the driver software.
2. While that's downloading, install VirtualBox:

   sudo apt-get install virtualbox
3. Add your user to the "vboxusers" group (very important):

   sudo useradd -G vboxusers *username*
4. Log out, and back in for this to take effect (also very important).
5. Open the virtual machine.
6. Install the *Guest Additions* in the VM.
7. Install the *M95 driver software*.
8. **Make a snapshot of the VM.**
9. You are now done with setting up the VM.

### Modifying Mouse Configs

*Note: You will probably want to have a second mouse on hand.*

1. Open the VM, if you haven't already.
2. In the VirtualBox tool bar, go to Devices > USB Devices > Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse. **This will disable your mouse outside of the virtual machine.** If you get stuck: Host + H to do a safe shutdown, Host + Q to force the VM to quit. (Host = RightCtrl by default.)
3. In the M95 driver software, make your changes and save them.
4. Export the config files and transfer them to the host for less headache later.
5. Exit the VM in however way you like.
6. All done!

## 2: Use Windows

Alternatively, you could just boot into Windows and make your changes there.