# Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse too sensitive / speed too fast. How to reduce speed?

Tags: mouse

The mouse control panel window slider does nothing.
The official thread does not seem to affect this particular mouse due to it's xinput props being different: [Reduce the Mouse Sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity)

Here's what I've tried:

```
xinput set-prop 9 "libinput Accel Speed Default" 2.88

X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

And:

```
xinput set-prop $MOUSE_ID "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2.88 

property 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Here are the props:

```
xinput list-props 9        
Device 'Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (287): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (288): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (289):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (290):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (291):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (292):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (293):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (296):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (297):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (298):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (299): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (300): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (301):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (302):    0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event2"
    Device Product ID (276):    6940, 6918
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):   1



 jonny  ~  xinput list-props 11
Device 'Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (292):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (293):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (276):    6940, 6918
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):   1



 jonny  ~  xinput list-props 10
Device 'Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (276):    6940, 6918


 jonny  ~  xinput list-props 15
Device 'Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (292):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (293):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (276):    6940, 6918

xinput list-props 4
Device 'Virtual core XTEST pointer':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    XTEST Device (271): 1
xinput list-props 2 
Device 'Virtual core pointer':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

And:

```
xinput                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Ultimate           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Ultimate           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0807)                    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Ultimate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M95 Gaming Mouse          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer BlackWidow Ultimate           id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was super close:

```
xinput set-prop $MOUSE_ID "libinput Accel Speed" -0.9
```

Where

```
MOUSE_ID=`xinput list | grep -i Corsair | awk '{print $(NF-3)}' | cut -c4-5 | head -n 1
```

Per: https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't have `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` like me.

The values for `libinput Accel Speed` can be negative, e.g.

`xinput --set-prop 'pointer:Logitech MX Master' 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.5`

To find your mouse name:
`xinput | grep pointer`, don't forget to prefix it with `pointer:` as my mouse shows up as a keyboard too.